# How we can install magento 2.2.0 via command line comand?

Tags: magento2, php-7, cli, magento2.2.0

How we can **install magento 2.2.0** via command line command(CLI) using Ubuntu ?
Could you please some share command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 php bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" --key="admin" --session-save="files" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_2_db" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --base-url="http://local.magento.com/" --base-url-secure="https://local.magento2.com/" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --admin-email="pramod.kharade@example.com" --admin-firstname="Pramod" --admin-lastname="Kharade"
```

Comment: Just one change:
Encryption key must be 32 character string without any white space

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You can *install using Command*. Magento 2 has ability do that:

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
> --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
> --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
> --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
> --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
> ```

See more at Magento Dev doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Comment: Hello sir @Amit Bera i am trying to install magneto 2.4 using CLi getting this issue Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in y  
  our cluster

Answer (score 1):

Go to your root directory likes:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>

```
php bin/magento setup:install
--base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2/"
--db-host="localhost"
--db-name="databasename"
--db-user="databaseuser"
--db-password="databasepass"
--admin-firstname="Yourname"
--admin-lastname="Yourname"
--admin-email="borntowinanwar@gmail.com"
--admin-user="admin"
--admin-password="strongpassword"
--backend-frontname="admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=https://www.printkuchbhi.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=production --db-user=prod-user --db-password=awpVFGDXs5LBVC34 --admin-firstname=PrintKuchBhi --admin-lastname=Admin --admin-email=hello@printkuchbhi.com --admin-user=printkuchbhi --admin-password=printkuchbhi@123 --language=en_US --currency=INR --use-rewrites=1
```

Also, make sure there should not be any space between value. Like, there should not be `--admin-firstname=Print Kuch Bhi`. It will give error like,

```
Error: Too many arguments, expected arguments command
```

So, it should be `--admin-firstname=PrintKuchBhi`